# Any penalized ensemble classifiers in `Scikit-learn` that result in sparse solutions?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, sparse

Is there an ensemble classifier that results in sparse solutions for the feature vector like Lasso Regression?  With Logistic Regression, I can choose L1 penalization from the `penalty` hyperparameter.  Is my only option to build an ensemble with `VotingClassifier` to do this or is there an out-of-the-box ensemble classifier in `sklearn` that is known to produce sparse solutions?

Comment: I removed a bunch of backticks from your question text. Those are for denoting identifiers or code.

Comment: Why do you specifically want an ensemble method? Is lasso regression not doing what you want somehow?

Comment: SVM with L1 may be good for your use, but cannot think about a ensemble methods for that.

Comment: Sorry I went trigger happy happy the ticks.  Lasso regression is usually for predicting continuous values right? I need something to predict class.  Do you mean throwing the output into a logit function?  I wanted to use an ensemble method b/c I read that they are much more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Logistic Regression model with L1 penalization as your ensemble classifier. We will call that your Level 1 Model. This will give a final predicted class probability for each sample. The features of this ensemble learner (Level 1) are essentially the predicted probabilities for every sample from each of your Level 0 models. In other words, each feature of the Level 1 learner is a model from Level 0. While performing CV training/test maintain the same fold assignments for each level to try and prevent overfitting. In addition, it is imperative while testing an ensemble learner to keep a validation set, or a hold out set, that the Level 0 and Level 1 models have never seen.

Not sure if there is an out of the box solution included with scikit-learn, but easy enough to write your own.